# On OS X, can I see how a website renders on an iPhone?

Tags: macos

I am running OS X Lion with XCode installed and want to know how a website renders on an iPhone. Are there any utilities that do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch the iOS Simulator from the iOS SDK.